# How to change the number of column of raster data in R?

Tags: r, mapping, global, spatial, r-raster

I have two raster data, both have same resolution and origin. And both have 3600 columns.
I use r <- rotate(r) on one raster data to change the log from 0,360 to -180,180. but after this process, the number of columns of this raster data increases to 3601 from 3600. However I need to do a calculation of two raster data, and need the number of columns of two raster data to be same, which is 3600.

I expect to get a raster data with 3600 columns.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Have you considered doing this in `terra::rotate`?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.